# How to generate images using python?

Tags: python, graphics, visualization

How do PIL, numpy, matplotlib or any other data visualization library for that matter create graphs and visuals? What is going on in the background?
Can we generate a visual (may be something as simple as a circle) without importing the data visualization libraries, using the built-in libraries in python. And if so, what would be the piece of code for that?

Do these data visualization libraries use low level programming language to create visuals?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python language very well but I know numpy ,matplotlab libraries and I use them occasionally.Firstly let look how graphic tools work.Actually computers can't know green , blue , white etc...They can only know the numbers. 0's and 1's.Computer includes a lot of parts to run the operating systems and special tasks , for example if you want to play a game then you have to get a display card and attach it to your motherboard.Motherboards , display cards , other electronics components can onlye know the voltage levels , 0's for low voltage level , 1's for high voltage level.

```
If you understand how computer works basically then we can jump to how programming languages work.C , C++ , Python , Java or any other programming language do the same job actually.All of them reaches the machine  , tells something and machine do it's job.Some languages use virtual machine and can't reach the machine directly but it's not important for now.
```

Let look at your questions : libraries for graphics written by programmer and they have a lot of code sections.For example if you want to draw a circle you use draw.circle(); as an example.However at background draw.circle() has a lot of code sections.Images or graphics are 3 dimensional arrays .First dimension is lenght second dimension is width and  third dimension is colour.For an example if you want to create a black line then program fills the first array with 0xFFFF values(0xFFFF is defines the black colour in HTML) then all the others become 0x0000(if background is white).

0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000

0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000

0xFFFF,0xFFFF,0xFFFF,0xFFFF,0xFFFF,0xFFFF,0xFFFF,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000

0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000

0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000

In here you can see what I mean.This graph says that you have 9 x 5 pixel = 45 pixel graph and it contains white backgorund and black line in the middle.Everything basicaly is that which programming languages do.After that all the thing is increase the ability of pixels.

Are we create a code section which don't require any graphical library?I think yes , it's possible but you how to deal with a lot.And I think it's waste of time.

If you want you can analyze the numpy library with link: 
   https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy

Comment: Thanks for being so descriptive in your explanation. but I specifically mean to ask that how that background coding (as in case of draw.circle() method) as pointed out in your answer create images. Can we write a code instructing computer using the pixel position and specifying their colours without importing these libraries to generate an image.

Comment: This answer is hard to understand. Do SO users need very basic explanations about how computers and code works? Didn't think so.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendatitons.Actually answer is not only SS123 or professional programmer.I would like to give some descriptive info's about how are the graphics and programming languages related.This description is for general users who curious about this matters.